# will two SSD work as a RAID1 bootable device (enable Intel RST) installing ubuntu only

Tags: system-installation, raid, rst

I have two SSD, which I want to make a RAID1 and install ubuntu on it.
Unfortunately I dont have a hardware RAID, instead I found an alternative way: Fake RAID.
Using motherboard ASUS-WS C621E SAGE which support FakeRAID (and support Intel Rapid Storage Technology and Intel Virtual RAID on CPU), setting up the BIOS config, and reinstall Ubuntu. failed.

Question:

1. If Intel RST work on ubuntu, work on a bootable system disk. (I do not mean to create a raid on two data disks after booting into ubuntu)
2. If Intel Virtual RAID on CPU work on ubuntu, I haven't try on it as it need a key I dont have so far.
3. It is good enough to apply to software RAID?

Refer to 3 kinds of RAID: hardware RAID, software RAID and Fake RAID. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto